# How to implement a type-level max function over a union of literals, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Given a union of number literals, e.g.:

```typescript
type Values = 1 | 2 | 5
```

Is it possible to create a generic **type-level** function that extracts the maximum, i.e.:

```typescript
type Max<T> = ???

type V = Max<Values>
//   V = 5
```

Comment: Does it have to be a union, or can it be a tuple of literals?

Comment: Converting a tuple of literals into a union of literals is easy, but the reverse path is not. Though, I would love to see any hint for a possible solution, so choose whichever suits you the most.

Comment: I don't think there is a comparison operator with typescript, so you can't know that type `5` > type `1`. Anyway, I don't see any benefit.

Comment: Sure. With a comparison operator, it would be obvious. However, as the TypeScript type system is Turing complete, I wonder whether it exists any ingenious/hacky way to express inequalities within its type system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced support for [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) so the below code can be written more directly as:

```
type Max<N extends number, A extends any[] = []> =
    [N] extends [Partial<A>['length']] ? A['length'] : Max<N, [0, ...A]>;

type Values = 1 | 2 | 5;
type MaxValues = Max<Values>; // 5
```

and it works well enough for unions of non-negative integers less than 1000.  It's still has the same caveats as below with regards to unexpected inputs and bogging down the compiler, but some of the restrictions have been listed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgDwDwDkoQcCA7AJgZymwFcBbAIwgCcAaKAQXUxwKjmxAG0BdKAXig8AfPwCwAKChTBKXhix5CnAApwqwAJZwANknpDOAcm04A5sAAWh7rwD8DIyezmrvAFyxEqOpwAMdADog+m4hAG4JCVBIKAA1HWIIQgEARigAHygAJgyoAFYI8WjoeAR47UTkz2RyyvCoAHoG-IkgA)

---

Answer for TS4.0:

The tersest illegal (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)) version of `Max` I can come up with (that uses [variadic tuples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) slated to come out in TS4.0) is this:

```
type MaxIllegal<N extends number, T extends any[] = []> = {
    b: T['length'], r: MaxIllegal<N, [0, ...T]>
}[[N] extends [Partial<T>['length']] ? "b" : "r"];

type MaxValuesIllegal = MaxIllegal<Values>; // 5
```

That sort of illegal circularity works until it doesn't, which is one reason it's not supported.  If you put in a value other than a non-negative integer, it recurses until there's a compiler error:

```
type OopsNegative = MaxIllegal<-1 | 3>; // error! Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

This can probably be worked around, but it gets worse: the recursion here bottoms out after only a few dozen levels, so you can't even use a number like `55` without getting an error:

```
type OopsTooBig = MaxIllegal<3 | 55 | 9>; // error! Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

---

One alternative is to programmatically generate a helper type like `LEQ` consisting of all the non-negative integers less than or equal to a given key, up to some max value you can choose... here I'm doing 100 or 99 or something:

```
// console.log("type LEQ={"+Array.from({length:100},(_,i)=>i+":"+Array.from({length: i+1},(_,j)=>j).join("|")).join(", ")+"}")
type LEQ = { 0: 0, 1: 0 | 1, 2: 0 | 1 | 2, 3: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3, 4: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4, 5: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5, 6: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6, 7: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7, 8: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8, 9: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ... SNIP!
```

Then you can write some code to pluck out the right values without using illegal circularity:

```
type Same<T, U, Y = T, N = never> = [T] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T] ? Y : N : N;
type ToLEQ<N extends number> = { [K in keyof LEQ]: [N] extends [Exclude<LEQ[K], K>] ? never : K }[keyof LEQ]
type Max<N extends number, U extends number = ToLEQ<N>> = { [K in keyof LEQ]: Same<U, LEQ[K], K> }[keyof LEQ]
```

It works for your example:

```
type MaxValues = Max<Values>; // 5
```

This works for `55` now because we're not overloading the stack:

```
type NotTooBigAnymore = Max<3 | 55 | 9> // 55
```

It still doesn't work when you give it an unexpected value like `-1`, but here it at least just gives you the max value it has instead of going completely off the deep end:

```
type OopsNegativeOkayIGuess = Max<-1 | 3> // 99
```

and as I said you can probably work around it by filtering the passed-in value before running `Max` on it.  After all we have a big `LEQ` type sitting around:

```
type Max<N extends number, U extends number = ToLEQ<Extract<N, keyof LEQ>>> = { [K in keyof LEQ]: Same<U, LEQ[K], K> }[keyof LEQ]
```

And that gives you

```
type OopsNegativeOkayIGuess = Max<-1 | 3> // 3
```

which happens to be true (although `Max<1 | 2.5>` will be `1` which is false).

---

In any case, this is really pushing the compiler past anything I'd be comfortable recommending for a production code base.  Really we should be pushing for [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) to be implemented so that the compiler can just do math at the type level.  So you might want to go there and give it a  and possibly describe your (hopefully compelling) use case.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQIxQD5QBM+UArANwCwAUDaJFALJwAeAkgghAOaIA8AOSgQWwCADsAJunFIAtgCMIAJwA0UACrDRE6VDjiQAbQC6mKKYB85gN40oDqAoBcmowHIu47sAAW7k3VlV2Z2Th5+AXUjAAZ1ADpEjRNLGgBfIyMBMxExKXQjAAU4ZWAAS34NSw8vH38TMwB+KAAiBRaoVxblFpMqWmp6aFD4ZDQOLl4Ec1CJiIQ+UZRUS3IoAHp1shoaTaGoAHkAezBUAQjygDdoLFnwqb4AWlwCAGZVja2VZSPlAEJNOBoGVxKhgAZynBykdxFAyugRABjNCoMrXBAgKCSCAQMD6KRQMBHVCohQYuHiABmILKYniu3W+2Opw0RyOACEytwZqw5g9XiRSKQSABOD6bYTKH7-QEMEFgiEVaGw+HaZEktEQcnY3H4ySE4mk8kg6niWkQekDCWImGoI5ceIII7cAAULX2ABkAKIARQwNhaAGoAIJSuAgeKUn5yF02Wp+ZzYGIxNKqF0AfVUZQAlBhLGVAy1nEHQ8pw5Ho7H475XAXsKmM6oAFa5ywt+JNo4gt14FrZ7MdrviN3qPuFtJ9uhAqDen22KAxVxxHBLkjYdSEVcEF5EdSvLc4EjEN7qAAsB53x6gAoIp-UpAvR5IN6gp8F6gAbI+CFeX2+CMKBAfuoADs35EM+JD-mQJAfiQIHqAAHOBv5QYKsHwSQiHqCKKGQbe6FAZhBCIaK6hJnhbxoQBGEECBWGimuy7YNglHXtRMFEXRDEECKTFruuOCbgua5PlRBE0VxUD0SRjHbjEAlroQ5H7iJ25iexEmcVAcHcbJvH8duO7YFe2CvOR55qYeP74a+hE6cRUCkQZ8mKdupkvtgd44A+VmXrZ0GAQ5elOXJOAKUZSlrp50HYKQ5Ffn5Gl-vZunSTxUB8a5kXudFa6xUF2DATgYFJTZ4l2ZJwXpfpmWGTgxkefla6FWl2AITgyFlRBFWBbRNWhS54VuUJeXbgVa5tTJnXkbh3WoVpQVpdNzl1dlDVRduMUtZNa7Tdgq3YCKG6LvNAWpY5q1ZcNOWjVtzXbq1e1rod12EMuhCsWdvUXSFV31Sxm04Ntj27du+2vUeEVEIJhDCdD-k-VVy0ZddSYjSZY04BN25TS9a5vdDn1HspRCqQjyUcUtl1hejt2Y-d407bjz3bpDP5E5eV6EOZRCWRT5WaZV2ko7VaMI41WNeczOB42zBNQ0eXNHi+hDeYQvkCz1Qt9VJK20xLQNmQ9PlgyV+PboTSskyrR7QRrG6JVrC3C9Tf0GxjTVM6DLPgxbOBWz+ys-qr9tBYQxWEKVzvncjNNDXTG25Yz2My0VrOdQrHPWz+3Oh0e4dpVHG5dTHSMi-Ha03Und3AybcVm+1-tHYrQc2yHdsF0eRfTYQ2FEHNZc679A3-etgPJ3X3um775vy5brcw+3ZOdz+hdHr3q2EMd16nUPKVx+7CeG5PxvTw3s9N-PAeL8Tue2z+YfdxvR5b9drzLq8X371T-X68fnspY41lhnA6WciCc2XjzVeRB14-k3ked+0Mv57nhqJQWB8K5HyronCetcz6px9iAv218W7ZzbvfDuj8u4-h7q-RBz5kE7leKTV45N0Ha0wW7UeHt6Ze0ITPYhc9M4L3IUvShK9qFr2fvA+hP4kHPmYb+Xmrx+YcJdrraq-8cEn3wSDQR6cSEiJvmIu+RA84wI1jIogCD5GMMUc+ZRz5vKvE1uo2OWCeEAL4UAtOctjFkIgTncxD8+Y0KIHQn8b97FvCUc+F8qjnzxWvE7dx5duHaPFoAlO0siGGOEWA0RQSKEhKoWE6RtCX5RIYW8Jhjj4nOKSc+Yqrxo5pOHofLxOjslTwERfIRV8AmB3EaUyR5TYHWKjnIgeMTrxxLeAk6CrjmnPg6q8Uu7SuF-1RgDSWOTgH5MGYUkxxSRlw1CWrcJEcqlEGibUhxbwnFvCWUFV4aVWnPn7q8Qemzf56x2ePPZvTckGP8ccwJ71gnnLKZcipESbl9xqbvB514nnXheSst4011nPh3qePevzFrbLFrso2+j+mHIhuAyFJToVjNhRMypsjql2PubE+pCzGlvFee87Fq1vlQWXKeb+hLXbEsGt0nx+y-GgPZqcsxdLoFSMZfC5ltykUfxRSwhpzymlvF5Z83FgqoKCVPGg9SGC-laIBdXPBDNgUHLBXKmlZyLHKqsUymx0zt6zK-hy68iy9UpNWYat4118UmqgqTU87CLWcKtaLCVWSpUOplUY8FwyFVuvGR61VXqWUzLZXM-1bCuXXh5SGt4-Lw3Q2FVGqCvNTxqLjRokemTSWn3JU9dNzrIESKVTmuB+b1WsuReyx5Or0VBreZW681bjW3h3GahtUFvKnjcS2jxGSbW4KBQQkFFKnXUr7aMgdDLc3XLVYi0dmrx2osnYk7lmLrx8qNbeWtS6rwxtXVBZJp5UmbvSeKsetq91dsblSopLqs0XKfp6qZBafVFr9ROzluqn36tnTisNC7XyfpXbeaC66oLFVPG0wDHTPHtsBWS+u3aCm9qhdm89Q6EMjsLWO4tqGA1luWZhrFobrw1sjbeL9f4iNBX-VBDqp4NkUa2f8klNHO10Yg83TNwd6VwbzWx69HHb1cfvWhqdGHg0CarW+18H7623nE7+kj0moL91PD8+TCbK7Jprva-djrZXHqY7Bq5kT2NIc4yhozPH0PlufR8izOH30idfGJn9t5JNpTI05qCO9SAErc0SxTSaO16NU5fSDJzoOabPdpy9w69OhYM+F7VxnH3Rf4y+wTAqEuLps6+OzqWHO3mmrJrLgplykBFXlsVBWQO7to+fejRzGO0uY9V4LdWFF3qa5FkzrWzPtbi0J3DdbRMEdfBJgbr4hurRc6NwUglSDmusvG-L1qlOgbm30hbZWIUnsVfnOFNXdN3LC-M7bLW+N7di3OyzEbusndsyl18aXHO3mu9dHLd3BSk1ILGp7rbOnUfeyp+banSEaagf9lVgPbH6bqdx0tUWIczvM9D+LVnEvLoR4R+zt50tXZGwBaG42seCl5qQZteOt3Ad4V5-hB6vvqdvpVynF61vA4a6DhnO2mcGoO519ncOkunabTz18fPMu3nR0LncD3ReCm8kKNiCnXuFeU8VknpXFemOV5Y1jNP6t04i1r8HFaWfYcO11vDPXv3c-67zlHr40e3YAjbq8OP7eCmSaQADkugPTZl3auXvme3+eW4FgHauNWB628HjFbWofh-17DqP8PeuI+I-HwbFvXxW8xwBNPL5xeZ8FMVUg5Hc+Ue3W92bxPPuk6GUrinvvJn+424ZmvgbTPM-26ziPBuW9G652d03Umu+o4F2Qa3IuAKD8CkFbPgoOqkDkxP53iaZu6O8+Bz3ZPF-9pV37t6mvo1miiHjFq+mzs3sdofm3rHkjhdhlufpbsnmQKnnbgBHfiPo-oKP3KQK5q-u5tgp5oXr4nkkelBr9itkFgiurtXqAXXpDhAXvlAfhkfibnHmbgnsNsgYLn3mQAPhngBPfmlGPjgYKDvB+LlgQS9u-gXmBiVgMt9uTv-svvBqvr6prpvrttvg3vOpHtAZzrAcfhwafpdt3jdrwSntfmQLfsPgBCIdNM-uIbBMuB+BNtIVNi7h-j0j5mmgxqXq6uXlTpXjenQQ+gwToUwU3tZq3jHsYfAZ3mYUgT3igcLv3ugWQJgfYdgQBKtHgS4bBIJB+I9ojJPtLt4rLqQaCn5hQQFjCqtjQVXlqvQdOrrrvtERzslnAR3pwWfonhfhjlYekTfoIWQMITkWQHkddJIYUbBKTB+LjqUW-h5kVl-goZSl7vKj7u6oAYhsAZobxqHjvo3sJoboYXEewQkb0Ukf0TwZfnwbbiMRgXYWQA4WIQBNMdDG4XMbBLzB+BLksYQV0sQfIR7ooZsRVkvjsSvkARoSWloTrlhnofvgYV0fET0aYYgbcSkZYagdYens8UIVgQBI4VMQUUBDuMUb8bBN5B+Buh4ZorIRUSQdKmQTUeVpQUEaro0aEc0eEa0UiTDjETARcedokVidwTifcUMfwRkUPkSdkSSe8WQJ8bMUBFeAsTSbBMkh+DnoCTISsW7msWCRsb-t7lCYOjCXsXCfTgiUcboUKZ0cbmKdcRKUnriWkbKU8ZkS8Q-kqbkc4UBF8ZSRqS+P8dqbBMVB+OPvqZ4UyZKpUaydUSXrUWXvUdQVerQXyc1hEW0ScUdqwUYZcRiebskRYdKXicMTYaMUKMSWQKSYGTpMGT8UBGGdBHSZGbBB1B+C-rGYyYaUTu7nPj-gvuaSodCWobCchgcYzvaVEacQfucX1lcZifzncYMZWV6dWYSWMXWaIQGR8eSTpCGdSUBO2UtGlNGbBP3B+PgX2W2jup-kXn4YtgETBumRXjybTtmWDrmYKZAcKUue3sjn0ZKeWRuZ6Y8duT6Qqa8RMU4YeUGWqTpKGVqUBBeV2debBDvCBFIfeQTo+T4d-uCWaVsRaSxlaSFvsfCYceAR1guaic6SfqWdieBVflWQSTBbuYqfWcqfkUhRSS2TpG2RGUBJedND2dhfBMuCBO4fhVRoRSmr4WySmRyXUVphmbVlmZti0VvnmciSwdHsuSWVwe6RWZBQITubWTxfuZMY2TMYJeqaeTpOeZ2UBBJatLedJfBIJCBCUZTAaUQasc+Spf4amYER+cEV+QHj+bXgKWHgZYBWicWSBTcWBb3jKVBZxfKdxXBf6XZYhU2chVSa2WhTpBhe5VhUBNdLhT5fBKTCBIsQFXGQOTPkOfLvPhmn-qegAZRetjaUHnaXRXrgxYWaKcxaZQMexVudlVkXlbxQeSqUed8U5aVWeaJTpOJVVTpDVdDLJfVfBLzCBACc1f2UFUaSFcmWFWpWmRpZ+ZmU0TpfyXpf+cwUlUxSYSxelakWgd6TldZfNbZQhUtQJceUJZqetehW5TpB5VJXRHtTuH5YdfBN5CBPSfJVPq7oOcacOSRaOWReOZaZOdadOTRbOcNe0aNUZcBQgWuVKRBb9dBf9eMflcDfxUVY5Shc5eGVDWJZhUBJ5btXVXRFeI1SjfBMkiBHqadQ+dPk+VUYeuyT9upVVppUDo9evrpdofpY6WcclS6aueYRlZuVlbYbBX6QtQVSDRzWDatcJWVR2XzZVQLXDdJAjQdXRC+MdRLfBMVCBDGTLQRXLUReseQTdRFXdVFQ9byU9TmfFccYlU6WwQbV9WZQzfiWbblRbUDWSaDStVzWtS5RtbqfzTpILd5XRIjaLV7dBGjb7fBB1CBL2YHQpcHUpcRaafjZCYTRRcTVRQNRvrRfXvOQWdTd0alW6VNQ8ZZVxQDdnQ2YVQ5bbQXfbZDeVdDVeS7dVRXdJFXcjXRLXUFFLQ3fBP3CBHeS3Zjd4e3aHUrcoT1aoTpuoaTbaUPYwfRaPbEcZRPXTWxdPXKXNfPXxaqZzSVavUXbzZtaXZJdvfDcLdJNXeLXREfctNNE3fBDvIhHhZfeUQmSyamqFa+eFe+ZHdydHd+bHb+fHQ6QBUnUWSnZNeudNabTWSzZbWzSA8vWAxDRA+vU7TDdtV5XA5XR7dJDXT7XRKg6fRg1hMuIhHJTg-nsyaCbjZ3V1WOQ-ROU-VOSDmTdrnOR-foWNd-bTUbT9Rnaw3uQvdbUvfndwyJZAyXc7WXa7bVSIyLfvdJIffXXRGg6tOfbI1hIJIhP5ZaoFcCcFQrQrqRd3Zo0TdoyTbo6-eTcPYYyicYzTeKb-cbRZQA76W8YtezbYyeYXTzXw1A84zAztTvftR457Ug9JCgyfXRP49dFg0E1hKTIhE1WEy1eddjZdYrapcrbdarfdVpRrSAc9dra9R0XrR9SuanVPZlTPczVY8A8tSU+A2U47RUwI1vdU8I7vaI2LQfRI9JFIy0zIyRNDPI501hLzIhCdb02dRExdVE51UthHWM1HRMzHZrdM4iQlbrYufrRNaBWncw6s4AwU1bUU82XbTwzsxVfsy47A27fA0jfU2c8gz49JH49c05LczuCEw81hN5IhOjYo14XIR9h1SOeowTXE73Qk-3S-YNW-ZEWk4ZV-Zk66dk+YxxZnXPbCxw5s+DQ4+U046i1U0Ixi+4wg5497bi5I809JK04EyRCS1eN0+S1hMkohNLS87LVjW1TjfS3jYy7E39o-dTjoxrno2AakyNZ-SKSY1k2Yx6YzbNfk-BbnTbXY6hWvbs9K5vWi4c-K8c3U2Iw03Xaq749I3RG08S-cyRC+E8-q1hMVIhAHca0Haa-LUmUM9dSM9871X3f1ey4PSk+-S60Y2PeiT-Z6+Zd68K2wznfZQiyvUi65fw2G7K0LQq1izGzi403i-7Ym9JMmx0yRDq+m9BJS1m1hB1IhM3Xm63QWyHSaWHaWyQz82Q38xQwC3HS9cC7Q-M8neC2lZC--X9TC36528VUG7wyG1tQc3K241G4q9i14+c8fQm1c0m5q05Nq2SyRAu0FIa8u1hP3IhBfeu1fbS7Pha2o183u+W6y5W0kxyzW1y3W+kw2ylaY2WTk625YzZdY-C0+9zb23s-2+XUc7U9+yO7+yqxc2q+g0BzczO05HO3qyRJB2lDmzB1hDvCKNgwh7gyCXS8XiW-fTa1o3a4kw68k-oxTfmfW7y+PcR6xaRxY1Ze25R5w4GzR8XW++Gx++7dG6c6x2O-G-i5OwE9x1q6m05PO5myREJytKtHB6KMuCKAo5J0o3gyoyhzu-J1QeM+rf81MyezM2e29XQ+NZ9Yw-TVC3k+baK-68UxKw7Si-R641Z8xzZ8q3Z+xwB+q4S+0y57O2B05BB0uyRN56J356KIJCKKE89n028wMx8wy2h9sfE0p2y9h9W2p865Ta60Bdpx6yR4KzNW2+s4U8Z1sz22Z9Awx5G0x8OyV94-ZxO4B1O8B3c7V2m-x05IJ9ByRD59dOJ216KKTCKD011684Tma4M9E13ZyZFQe9F0e7F1Q6ewnSC4xZeylxC8sybdC766zdl12-Y3lxvbDei5+9t4g6O3G+Vw54d050Szx6S2d+Bx505F5yJyRLd9DAFw96KLzCKM8y9ya9fYmQQ1dUQ+Heh7ayEf9zOeN7W5N5p263y4bXN16-p7PYZxs3nat5K6+xt4V5i+j7Z5j-+9j5V1x3jzV7x3VxmwJ4105M1+T617xDuB1zT6KN5CKFS0FzS8ozJy+Uod1Qp0N1zzFZQ3FUDzQ4lxe-Q1e5PUw7e0zfe7D4+6A8+8i0j4I4O1+zt+I2xyrwd2r0d85yB657q0T7r551d05Dd0b5lCb1eE9+b6KMkiKEawz-m0z-g8pazw7xo07yy8N1hypzh7z3h-zwR1p42zp99aL0K+R4DUZ+K4izL-l8jxG6j3vT+6V8r5c4n7j9Vyn6d25+d4u5n012T05BT-d7xAXy+HT8X6KMVCKLm+Xxu5X6F7J2z7u4Nw3y79Rap063zxpx34LzN-y82+nX3wZ0t3Cyt7l8G6P0j41NJ+LHafk0wq6cck+GvRflr0J71dieUHdftdxa68RKe+fM3rxGgiW9D+ooDqCKDXan9EOtvZDpf1r5Mt6+DRchq72PaA94uwPc9qCwWYmUIe-vFZhlyzpZcQ+XDMPrR1DZj9LOCvJVntyx4J9IB8-FNkvzT7wCM+JPLPquxQGZQ0B1PXiHvywFBRS+uA0UP3BFDwdCBUnSJkW0+5WtvupDXYiN2b5jdH+bfZ-jy1f5d9Zuunebiw2-4UdJeAbaXojz7b8Co+aPIQX+1n5iDp2mvAnsv3T4Xc9ewnZAYb1QHb9Mou-IvrxHUFpRj+Wg0UHxDSD7AAAWtkMyHmAAASk2j4ClFSAqQAYPsAADKcAOQBAD4AaB1AAAVXUAABNcwHUKgBCAsA4gCANcGUDWAsARgZINoDyB6AjA9QpoBYDGFDDdABQQYc0BaGuAhACw-oPsFZCzhBAUw-IFAFkCKAVAfQqADYAsAABpCkFAAADWEAEAEcEpAzhfQJgVwFkByA6BNhRgL0CwERDIBsQfAWcEYEOGBAoAhwywOMK6E9DOg-wqABkHOGXDrhs4EwFOAYChB1huQaYVsPkBKA1AUAeoRsL0DbC0RrQo4GsNeHAAywiIYAIIHUCQirhNwn0JYBpHzgfhJwikdCNuGuBKh1QvgI0KpE-C-hAI8EUYEZFUjYRZQ6cCMEQDLAeQLARYKKLQDigtgpAHYIMGnDMgzgFwTUAcFOHhg2AAAcWWDoBbgrAJ4MwmsAShXgcI6AAICODABWQHILkMGEMByBfgNwJgPqMHzqCjRsouUQMCgDyjvRAwIAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer (i.a., `ToLEQ` is so neat). For the sake of the regular TypeScript's user base, I link here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-573350993 about the risk of using recursive conditional types. I also link https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32131#issuecomment-622470657 to show how confusing this affair is becoming.

Comment: Is this still illegal? It seems to work just fine with `type OopsTooBig = MaxIllegal<3 | 55 | 9>`. Is that after the PR was done? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980

Comment: updated, TS4.1 introduced support for recursive conditional types

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy. I created a monster that seems to work, but because of the limitations of circular types, it cannot be done as a single step.

```
type DropFirst<T extends TupleLike> = T extends readonly [any, ...infer U] ? U : [...T];

type Longer<T, U extends TupleLike> = U extends [] ? T : T extends [any, ...U] ? T : U;

type TupleLike<T = unknown> = readonly T[] | readonly [T];

type Head<T> = T extends [infer U, ...any[]] ? U : never;

type TupleOf<T, Length extends number, Queue extends any[] = []> = {
  done: Queue,
  next: TupleOf<T, Length, Prepend<T, Queue>>;
}[Yield<Queue, Length>]

type Yield<Queue extends any[], Length extends number> =
  Queue['length'] extends Length
    ? "done"
    : "next"

type Prepend<T, U extends any[]> =
  ((head: T, ...tail: U) => void) extends ((...all: infer V) => void)
    ? V
    : []

type FindLongestTuple<T extends readonly number[][], Accumulator extends number[] = []> = {
  done: Accumulator;
  next: FindLongestTuple<DropFirst<T>, Longer<Head<T>, Accumulator>>;
}[T extends [] ? 'done' : 'next'];

type GenerateTuples<T extends readonly number[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: TupleOf<1, T[K] & number>
}

/**
 * Usage:
 */
type Input = [4, 5, 6, 1, 2];

type Step1 = GenerateTuples<Input>;
type Step2 = FindLongestTuple<Step1>
type Result = Step2['length']; // 6
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=42&pc=10#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgezAMQJZwM7ADwBUoQAewEAdgCYZS4CuYANhADKoDWEAfFALzUHFlKUOBACG5BKXogoAbVGkQAGigA6dalIAzCHCgBVALpQA-AagAuOetW5DAbgCwAKBehIUJpIDmuvCv1+EgoqWgZmNk4ecyJgoVljM3wrfFjBKnlFFRsjUz4rfSdXZ3doMMYWdjxomlJWUgQAd1IuXhFxSWlqBKgAH2ExCSkZWTsit3BoAAlBvFa+NJC5TR09fWz1BRAExPMrUggAN11xksnqOkYAeS1-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)

I bet there is a simpler way to do that. ;-)

Comment: +1 for the brilliant hint on migrating to tuples world to leverage `length`. However, your `Longer` function only works in a "one by one increment" world. So, an input like `[4, 5, 7, 1, 2]` results in `5` instead of `7`. Anyway, you're on something ;)