# Recursive type definition results in “Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite (ts 2589)” TypeScript error when using type

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, infinite-recursion, recursive-type

I’m encountering the TypeScript error `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite (ts 2589)` when using a recursive type definition on a typed const. Here’s a simplified version of my type code:

```js
// Type aliases
export type Version = number;
export type Shape = object;
export type ShapeRecord = Record<Version, Shape>;

// Recursive Max
type Max<N extends number, A extends unknown[] = []> =
  [N] extends [Partial<A>["length"]]
  ? A["length"] & N
  : Max<N, [0, ...A]>;

// Type helpers
type ShapeVersion<TShapeRecord extends ShapeRecord> = keyof TShapeRecord & Version;
type LatestShapeVersion<TShapeRecord extends ShapeRecord> = Max<ShapeVersion<TShapeRecord>>;

// Helper function
const getLatestVersion = <TShapeRecord extends ShapeRecord>(shapeRecord: TShapeRecord): LatestShapeVersion<TShapeRecord> =>
  Math.max(...Object.keys(shapeRecord).map(Number)) as LatestShapeVersion<TShapeRecord>;
```

(Recursive `Max` taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976061/234910))

When I try to use the `getLatestVersion` function on an untyped object, everything works well:

```js
const untypedShapeRecord = {
  5: {},
  4: {},
  3: {},
  2: {},
  1: {},
};
const latestVersion = getLatestVersion(untypedShapeRecord);
//    ^? const latestVersion: 5
```

However, when I add the `ShapeRecord` type to my const, TypeScript suddenly complains that the type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite:

```js
const typedShapeRecord: ShapeRecord = {
  5: {},
  4: {},
  3: {},
  2: {},
  1: {},
};
const notLatestVersion = getLatestVersion(typedShapeRecord); // Error: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite (ts 2589)
//    ^? const notLatestVersion: any
```

The version numbers are currently not higher than 6, so the actual level of recursion should be that high. This number is not expect to ever get much higher than 20 - two digits at most. I've tested the `Max` type with higher values, and it seems to die when values are higher or equal to 1000.

How can I modify my types to avoid this error? Is there a better way to achieve the same functionality without running into this issue?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQIYBsCWCDOt0ChYA9oB7AJwBdRSZ4A1WY9FQgO1AF5QmBXAWwCM6A3LgIlylOKADKACwQT2hXgCtYAY1JD8RMhSpTZcAEpqSAEzahjqswB5a9RkwA0%20ubAB8Q7CEtrODgDd4AFkEPGxxELCbADlQfFJYJlN0Dh5%20YhcAQXi8ROTUziYAayZCAHcmAG0AXQta9zZsUFAqmLqEpJTWgAUEMjQkGyz3KoAiJCSAc1JpMZqa5tAAflAs8cmmGbm6gDJQGKWALlBQvFiXKoAGFwA6e6yaz2xvMCgJaVgkOHoIvRk3PYGMwbOAAUYTMRzJ0Cq4IdYoY12MVYJBCAAzCDg2BWMygfZAxxCSKgAAyCES6FI2MJILBBhxkOheS6qWxuMRFjONhpdGBTFB7KZ7mer1AAAkvj9QOiiupHNhrEwqaAprBSOTKaRaSx2IKGRzmflukKEaZ3AAKdAGpkneluQ0AShOmqw1IZOv1DuFbHcS1Cs1u3DCFvutwA8so1KRbijIOgrTazY6g3ILTF0nRHY7EKlXVTeQ46aazKKxQB1EjFHBKlVFSKmEtQiwAbyWAFYTi2AL5OJYAFi7vaWAGYh32WgAmcdLACMM%207Qlr5CQFLdOosao1a6pOot9aojaTZkdQh8LVAAD1li8fAARQhYJgAcnI5SriuYKobTdMJ1-rYdjOLSDqAPYTqAY5gcOU7AaA87QX2i6fsq5BlNuWobuwW75tqfKOBaP7HlCp6gD4ACixDECQdp6CgqEIEwpBoMxzCgCgqT4KoWAMEESCQKApiwLA0CIMkoBEOgDC8Px7FMOi9EoIkoCEakk7tgAHAAnI6YoXteQA)

Comment: Your problem is that `ShapeRecord` has `number` as a key, so you're making the tuple longer and longer looking for the nonexistent time when `number` is its length.  You should just bail out if `N` is `number`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NDadlm). (And no, you can't divine `5` from that, since you've clobbered that info with your annotation) There are other ways to maybe approach this, and there are undoubtedly other edge cases, but this will get you past this hurdle. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?